# InvalidOperationException deserializing Atom XML

Tags: c#, xml, deserialization

I'm using this C# code to read an XML RSS feed and deserialize it against a model:

```
List<RssFeedModel> rssFeedItems = new List<RssFeedModel>();
var url = @"http://mimijumi-dev.myshopify.com/blogs/news.atom";
string result;
using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
{
    var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, url);
    var response = await httpClient.SendAsync(request);
    result = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
}
XmlDocument xdoc = new XmlDocument();
xdoc.LoadXml(result.ToString());
XmlNodeReader xreader = new XmlNodeReader(xdoc);
XmlSerializer deserializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<RssFeedModel>));
rssFeedItems = (List<RssFeedModel>)deserializer.Deserialize(xreader);
```

Here's the model code:

```
[XmlRoot("feed", Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom")]
public class RssFeedModel
{
    [XmlElement("title")]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("content")]
    public string Content { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("link")]
    public string Link { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("id")]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("published")]
    public DateTime PublishDate { get; set; }

}
```

This throws the following exception:

```
InvalidOperationException: <feed xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom'> was not expected.
Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.XmlSerializationReaderList1.Read3_ArrayOfRssFeedModel()
```

for this line:

```
rssFeedItems = (List<RssFeedModel>)deserializer.Deserialize(xreader);
```

I followed the instructions in this StackOverflow post to try to fix it: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1232328/177416 but it's still blowing up.

**UPDATE**: Here's the XML it's trying to deserialize:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<feed xml:lang="en-US" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:opensearch="http://a9.com/-/spec/opensearch/1.1/" xmlns:s="http://jadedpixel.com/-/spec/shopify">
  <id>http://example.com/blogs/news.atom</id>
  <link rel="alternate" type="text/html" href="http://example.com/blogs/news"/>
  <link rel="self" type="application/atom+xml" href="http://example.com/blogs/news.atom"/>
  <title>News</title>
  <updated>2015-05-14T08:48:00-04:00</updated>
  <author>
    <name>Author</name>
  </author>
  <entry>
    <id>http://example.com/blogs/news/28298241-sixth-post</id>
    <published>2015-05-14T08:48:00-04:00</published>
    <updated>2015-05-14T08:48:49-04:00</updated>
    <link rel="alternate" type="text/html" href="http://example.com/blogs/news./28298241-sixth-post"/>
    <title>Sixth Post</title>
    <author>
      <name>Author</name>
    </author>
    <content type="html">
      <![CDATA[Mauris ipsum. Nulla metus metus, ullamcorper vel, tincidunt sed, euismod in, nibh. Quisque volutpat condimentum velit. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Nam nec ante. Sed lacinia, urna non tincidunt mattis, tortor neque adipiscing diam, a cursus ipsum ante quis turpis. Nulla facilisi. Ut fringilla. Suspendisse potenti. Nunc feugiat mi a tellus consequat imperdiet. Vestibulum sapien. Proin quam. <br><br>Etiam ultrices. Suspendisse in justo eu magna luctus suscipit. Sed lectus. Integer euismod lacus luctus magna. Quisque cursus, metus vitae pharetra auctor, sem massa mattis sem, at interdum magna augue eget diam. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Morbi lacinia molestie dui. Praesent blandit dolor. Sed non quam. In vel mi sit amet augue congue elementum. Morbi in ipsum sit amet pede facilisis laoreet. Donec lacus nunc, viverra nec, blandit vel, egestas et, augue. Vestibulum tincidunt malesuada tellus. Ut ultrices ultrices enim.]]>
    </content>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <id>http://example.com/blogs/news/28297985-fifth-post</id>
    <published>2015-05-14T08:48:00-04:00</published>
    <updated>2015-05-14T08:48:16-04:00</updated>
    <link rel="alternate" type="text/html" href="http://example.com/blogs/news/28297985-fifth-post"/>
    <title>Fifth Post</title>
    <author>
      <name>Author</name>
    </author>
    <content type="html">
      <![CDATA[Curabitur sit amet mauris. Morbi in dui quis est pulvinar ullamcorper. Nulla facilisi. Integer lacinia sollicitudin massa. Cras metus. Sed aliquet risus a tortor. Integer id quam. Morbi mi. Quisque nisl felis, venenatis tristique, dignissim in, ultrices sit amet, augue. Proin sodales libero eget ante. Nulla quam. Aenean laoreet. Vestibulum nisi lectus, commodo ac, facilisis ac, ultricies eu, pede. <br><br>Ut orci risus, accumsan porttitor, cursus quis, aliquet eget, justo. Sed pretium blandit orci. Ut eu diam at pede suscipit sodales. Aenean lectus elit, fermentum non, convallis id, sagittis at, neque. Nullam mauris orci, aliquet et, iaculis et, viverra vitae, ligula. Nulla ut felis in purus aliquam imperdiet. Maecenas aliquet mollis lectus. Vivamus consectetuer risus et tortor. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer nec odio. Praesent libero. Sed cursus ante dapibus diam. Sed nisi. Nulla quis sem at nibh elementum imperdiet.]]>
    </content>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <id>http://example.com/blogs/news/28297665-fourth-post</id>
    <published>2015-05-14T08:47:00-04:00</published>
    <updated>2015-05-14T08:47:43-04:00</updated>
    <link rel="alternate" type="text/html" href="http://example.com/blogs/news/28297665-fourth-post"/>
    <title>Fourth Post</title>
    <author>
      <name>Author</name>
    </author>
    <content type="html">
      <![CDATA[Duis sagittis ipsum. Praesent mauris. Fusce nec tellus sed augue semper porta. Mauris massa. Vestibulum lacinia arcu eget nulla. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Curabitur sodales ligula in libero. Sed dignissim lacinia nunc. Curabitur tortor. Pellentesque nibh. Aenean quam. In scelerisque sem at dolor. Maecenas mattis. Sed convallis tristique sem. <br><br>Proin ut ligula vel nunc egestas porttitor. Morbi lectus risus, iaculis vel, suscipit quis, luctus non, massa. Fusce ac turpis quis ligula lacinia aliquet. Mauris ipsum. Nulla metus metus, ullamcorper vel, tincidunt sed, euismod in, nibh. Quisque volutpat condimentum velit. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Nam nec ante. Sed lacinia, urna non tincidunt mattis, tortor neque adipiscing diam, a cursus ipsum ante quis turpis. Nulla facilisi. Ut fringilla.]]>
    </content>
  </entry>
 </feed>
```

Comment: @jdweng: please see update to the question; it now has the XML.

Comment: Have you tried: 'XmlSerializer deserializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(RssFeedModel));' ? Also looks like your RssFeedModel class is for feed entry but your trying to serialized feed into it. You will mist likely need two classes - one for feed and one for entry and the one for feed will contain a collection/list of entries.

Comment: Looks like the XML you are trying to deserialize is much more complex than your c# model.  I did find [this XSD](https://tools.oasis-open.org/version-control/browse/wsvn/cmis/trunk/SchemaProject/schema/ATOM.xsd) for the [Atom Publishing Protocol](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5023), if that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.  You had link as a string and it needed to be a separate class.  Also added List<> objects and Attributes so you can see a sample of how to properly deserialize an XML.

```css
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(RssFeedModel));
            XmlTextReader reader = new XmlTextReader(FILENAME);
            RssFeedModel rssFeedModel = (RssFeedModel)xs.Deserialize(reader);

        }
    }
}
[XmlRoot("feed", Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom")]
public class RssFeedModel
{
    [XmlElement("title")]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("link")]
    public List<Link> link { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("entry")]
    public List<Entry> entry { get; set; }
}
[XmlRoot("link")]
public class Link
{
    [XmlAttribute("rel")]
    public string rel { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute("type")]
    public string type { get; set; }
}
[XmlRoot("entry")]
public class Entry
{
    [XmlElement("id")]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("published")]
    public DateTime PublishDate { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("content")]
    public Content content { get; set; }
}
[XmlRoot("content")]
public class Content
{
    [XmlAttribute("type")]
    public string type { get; set; }
    [XmlText]
    public string text { get; set; }
}
​
```

Comment: Thanks, @jdweng. How did you know to split the classes into these?

Comment: The feed only contains the top-level "feed" and nothing from the "entry" items. Any solutions?

Comment: Only only de-serialized the top levels to show how it is properly done.  Each nested level of tags is a class with the leaf tag and object like int, string, bool, and DateTime.  Attributes contain an equal sign in the XML.

Comment: Thanks, @jdweng. I couldn't get this to pull both the `content` and `published` of the `entry` nodes. It would pull only the `content` and I spent the entire day trying to get it to work. Ultimately, I ended up looping over the XML nodes and populating a List of RssFeedModel items.

Comment: Easy fixes.  Content need to be moved and made a separate class.

Comment: Thanks again, @jdweng! How did you know how to do that? Is there somewhere I can read and learn about complex XML deserialization? Again, thanks :)