# Specific Namespace in XML Deserialization fails

Tags: c#, xml-namespaces, xml-deserialization

I looked for an issue but couldn't find the answer the this particular case, so here is the issue.

When trying to deserialize a xml string into a strong type object I got the following message:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: There is an error in XML document (1, 2). ---> System.InvalidOperationException: <GetPointOfDelivery_Out xmlns='urn:webbeB2B:webservices:v0'> was not expected.
    at Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.XmlSerializationReaderGetPointOfDelivery_Out.Read16_GetPointOfDelivery_Out()
```

Although the class has to my opinion the correct namespace attribute value defined, being :

```
[XmlType(AnonymousType = true, Namespace = "urn:webbeB2B:webservices:v0")]
    public class GetPointOfDelivery_Out
    {
        [XmlElement("POD")]
        public POD[] POD
….
}
```

The source string looks like this:

```
<out:GetPointOfDelivery_Out xmlns:out="urn:webbeB2B:webservices:v0">
    <out:POD>
        <out:PODID>FT}UntwKNFlX0000h100Dm</out:PODID>
 ….
    </out:POD>
    <out:ErrorMessage>
        <out:MsgType>S</out:MsgType>
    </out:ErrorMessage>
</out:GetPointOfDelivery_Out>
```

I use the following code to deserialize the string

```
var xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));

            using (var textReader = new StringReader(xml))
            {
                return (T)xmlSerializer.Deserialize(textReader);
                }

(Where T is GetPointOfDelivery_Out and xml the example given above.)
```

Any help is welcome.

Comment: Usually, if I'm having issues with deserialization, I'll create a toy project that constructs the *object graph I'm expecting* and then ask the XML Serializer to serialize that graph, then compare the XML for differences. With incomplete definitions here though, it's difficult for someone else to do that job.

Answer (score 2):

While looking somewhat deeper into stack overflow I found the answer in the following post:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/1232328/1145146

I added the XmlRoot attribute on the target class to be deserialized

```
[Serializable]
[XmlRoot("GetPointOfDelivery_Out", Namespace = "urn:webbeB2B:webservices:v0")]
[XmlType(AnonymousType = true, Namespace = "urn:webbeB2B:webservices:v0")]
public class GetPointOfDelivery_Out
```